# Synonyms page says suggested synonym gets declined at "--2" votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar

Just thought it was weird that there's an extra minus sign in the tooltip when the suggested synonym has a negative vote. When you hover over a synonym with a negative vote, it reads:

[image: total votes (when a synonym gets a score of --2 it is automatically declined)]

Comment: Rather than risk vote-inflation on such an important and highly-used part of the system, it seems that _Boolean arithmetic_ is used to calculate vote totals for synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better late than never... This will be fixed in the next build.