# Tooltip for negative reputation change is strange; shows "--"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, activity-dropdown

So I lost… negative negative two reputation! Technically right but completely strange.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The title should read “shows -- instead of +”. [I wonder what’s up with the em dash?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193572/question-titles-collapse-double-minus-signs-to-mdash)

Comment: I'm surprised at how quickly that meta post became relevant!!!

Comment: It should show neither IMHO: 2 are lost. "+2 are lost" would be confusing. "-2 are lost" is false (two negatives)

Comment: Seems to be a [recurring theme now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120293/synonyms-page-says-suggested-synonym-gets-declined-at-2-votes).

Comment: Still present as of 2013-08-26

Comment: Looks like one of those little yet annoying bugs that can last forever... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m going to go ahead and mark this as complete; the new top bar out on Meta fixes this bug (or at least it no longer applies, but we don’t have a tag for that).

Comment: It's called close --> off-topic --> can no longer be reproduced. ;)